# Is it possible to have a Git repo combined from multiple repos?

Tags: git

I have a PHP framework in a Git repo and I want to use it as a basis for projects. Each new project should be in its own repo. However, I would like changes made to framework be pulled back to framework repo as well.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Your use case sounds prototypical for me to use submodules.

[Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) also covers that topic.